# Parameter passing to a shell script using BashOperator in Airflow 2.0

Tags: shell, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am using airflow 2.0 and recently came up with a problem. So in my dag, I am calling a shell script by passing arguments like date and hour and in the script it should ideally fetch the value and perform some operation. But unfortunately, the values are not getting substituted.

```
    Date='{{ (next_execution_date + macros.timedelta(hours=9,days=-3)).strftime("%Y%m%d") }}' //global    
    BashOperator=(task_id="",
    dag=dag,
    bash_command=''' 
    echo "hi" 
    '''
    +
    ''' 
    /path /file.sh Date Hr 
    '''
    )
```

In the shell script file.sh:

```
echo "Date is $1"
echo "Hour is $2"
```

Checked the logs and it printed- Date is Date, Hour is Hr. Can anyone please help me with correct way to pass these arguments?

Answer (score 1):

You might have an issue with a quote being off at one point, hard to tell from your question.

This works for me (Airflow 2.5.1):

DAG

```py
from airflow import DAG
from pendulum import datetime
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

with DAG(
    dag_id="scripting_dag",
    start_date=datetime(2022,12,10),
    schedule="@daily",
    catchup=False,
) as dag:

    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id="t1",
        bash_command="my_script.sh",
        env={
            "my_date": "{{ (next_execution_date + macros.timedelta(hours=9,days=-3)).strftime('%Y%m%d') }}",
            "my_hour": "{{ (next_execution_date + macros.timedelta(hours=9,days=-3)).strftime('%H') }}"

        }
    )
```

script my_script.sh:

```bash
echo $my_date
echo $my_hour
```

Logs

```
[2023-02-03, 16:35:28 UTC] {subprocess.py:75} INFO - Running command: ['/bin/bash', '-c', 'echo $my_date\necho $my_hour']
[2023-02-03, 16:35:28 UTC] {subprocess.py:86} INFO - Output:
[2023-02-03, 16:35:28 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 20230201
[2023-02-03, 16:35:28 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 01
```